# Converter for input (composite USB) and output (2x PS2)

Tags: hardware, usb, keyboard-video-mouse

It seems there are plenty of PS/2 to USB converters but want we need is a composite USB input and 2x PS/2 outputs (keyboard and mouse).
An example application: a server without USB ports but 2x PS/2 ports. KVM cable is a VGA and composite USB (i.e. single USB cable for keyboard/mouse).
Does such product even exist?

Comment: I finally managed to find it!

http://intrl.startech.com/Server-Management/KVM-Switches/PS-2-to-USB-Keyboard-and-Mouse-Adapter~PS22USB

> * Supports the use of combo 2-in-1 keyboard and mouse connections (wired only)
> * ...
> * No driver or software required...

Exactly what we were after, just not as cheap as hoped (at the moment of writing this Newegg seems to have a special on this item).

Comment: Cool! As you say, expensive though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing to watch for is that a lot of devices are *designed* to be 'converted' so those USB -> PS/2 converters which come with a lot of mice nowadays are actually dumb pin converters with the actual conversion being performed by the mouse itself. In other words, they're not converters as such and won't work with just any device.

I'm afraid I've not seen the style of device you're after, though - it'd require some decent electronics.

For example, this here:

http://www.ebuyer.com/124082-startech-usb-to-ps-2-keyboard-adapter-plug-usb-keyboard-into-ps-2-port-gc46fmkey

Would rely on the keyboard switching to 'PS/2' mode.